# Given csv file , I need to print those sentence which are most similar based upon the similarity score

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp

For a given `.csv` file containing 'N'  ID, sentence
Problem is to find most matched sentence in given csv file

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to filter all the sentences containing 'N', then use:

```py
import pandas as pd
file=pd.read_csv(r"the file's path")
df=pd.DataFrame(file)
df_new=[df!='N']
```

If you are seeking similarities, then this is an NLP question. In this case, you should code the sentences into sparse matrices first, then use K-means or other clustering methods to compare the similarities.